# Illegal syntax for subtype indication VHDL200X

Tags: vhdl, synthesis, xilinx-ise

I am trying to create a "dynamic" 2D array which I can set with generics in my entity.

I followed the example in https://s3.amazonaws.com/verificationhorizons.verificationacademy.com/volume-8_issue-3/articles/stream/vhdl-2008-why-it-matters_vh-v8-i3.pdf on page 32.

The declaration of my type within the package (TypeDeclarations):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package TypeDeclarations is

-- Type BusArray -----------------------------------------------------
-- Can be used by: DArray((Y - 1) downto 0)((X - 1) downto 0);      --
                                                                    --
    type TArray is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;    --
                                                                    --
----------------------------------------------------------------------
end package;
```

my entity:

```
-- Libraries
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

-- Own libraries
use work.TypeDeclarations.all;

entity DynamicRegisterSet is
    generic (
        INPUT_DATAWIDTH  : integer := 1;
        OUTPUT_DATAWIDTH : integer := 8;
        N_REGISTERS      : integer := 1);
    port (
        MCLK : in std_logic := '0';
        WE   : in std_logic := '0';

        -- input data
        DATA : in std_logic_vector((INPUT_DATAWIDTH-1) downto 0) := (others => '0');
        SEL  : in integer range 0 to (INPUT_DATAWIDTH-1) := 0;

        -- in/output data (register set)
        REGISTERSET : inout TArray((N_REGISTERS-1) downto 0)((OUTPUT_DATAWIDTH-1) downto 0) := (others => (others => '0')));
end DynamicRegisterSet;
```

This is the first time I'm using the updated compiler (VHDL200X), I don't think I am doing this wrong but else I wouldn't get this message:

> VHDL\CommonBlocks\DynamicRegisterSet\Sources\DynamicRegisterSet.vhd" Line 25: Illegal syntax for subtype indication

Anyone any suggestions? I would appreciate it very much, thanks!

Comment: There aren't 49 lines of code posted...

Comment: lines before that are comments, it gives the error at REGISTERSET : that is line 49

Comment: What tool are you using?

Comment: That information should be in the question, not in a comment. Better still, compile what you post so the errors match the code.

Comment: @Paebbels I'm using xilinx ISE 14.7 (64 bit)

Comment: @BrianDrummond I updated the error so it matches the code that I posted

Comment: @Paebbels come again? it has the option to switch compiler does it support like half of the functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xilinx ISE 14.7 has no VHDL-2008 support...

They support a hand full of VHDL-2002/2008 features, but unconstrained array elements are not supported.

Vivado added VHDL-2008 support in 2016.1 and sets it as default. But as far as I can see, it's no full VHDL-2008 support.

There is a Xilinx XST synthesis user guide listing these features in the VHDL section. (Sorry I don't have the UG number on my phone.)

Comment: It's okay, Thanks for all the support, I'm just baffled. I thought this change was sort of official and so small that I thought It was implemented fully to keep VHDL designs compatible. I gues I was wrong :). do you know for any change that this is also the case with other FPGA manufacturers?

Comment: The 2008 support in Altera Quartus Prime and Lattice Diamond is better. I have no info on Symplify but I suspect it's ever better.

Comment: I am using lattice diamond now but I got the same error now when trying to generate a test bench :p this is not over yet

Comment: Have you enabled VHDL-2008 for Diamond? Using 2008 in synthesis (x)or testbench are two completely different things... Are you simulating with Active-HDL?

Comment: Double click on your active design strategy, e.g. **Area**, navigate in the *Process* tree to **Synthesize Design -> LSE**. Then scroll down to the buttom and set **VHDL 2008** to **True**. (My Diamond version is 3.7)

Comment: Hmm, done that for synplify pro and LSE, my version of Diamond is also 3.7 and I am using synplify pro. Still its not working for me, I also can't generate schematic symbols. Could it be that I need to generate an hierarchy first? I saw someone do this in a tutorial on creating and testing a design, this was on a older version though and I couldn't find that option.

Answer (score 0):

## ISE

ISE has no VHDL-2008 support at all. Read more details on [Xilinx forum](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2015_3/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf) or from XST guide [ISE12](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx12_2/xst.pdf) [ISE14](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_7/xst.pdf)

> **Supported VHDL IEEE Standards**
>
> XST supports the following VHDL IEEE standards:
>
> - Std1076-1987
> - Std1076-1993
> - Std1076-2006
>
> Note Std 1076-2006 is only partially implemented.

## Vivado

Vivado has a set of synthetisable VHDL-2008 construct. Read more details in [UG901](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_2/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf)
(*Supported VHDL-2008 features* chapter)